# Why won't my AngularJS view load in Cordova?

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova

My `index.html` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    THIS WORKS NOW!
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And in `app.js`, I have:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
    }).when('/dashboard', {
      templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard.html'
    }).otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }
]);
```

So I run `cordova build ios` and it does it's magic to make an xcode project, which I then open and run. I see `THIS WORKS NOW!`, but I don't see the contents of my `home.html` file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that code from `app.js` wrapped in a function called by the `deviceready` event listener?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need bootstrap angular:

`app.js` is fine!

but remove `ng-app` inside the tag `<body>` and start angular when the event `onDeviceReady` has been triggered :

`index.js` file:

```
var app = {
    initialize: function () {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function () {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function () {
        angular.element(document).ready(function () {

            angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);

        });
    }
};
```

normally that is all you need to do.

Comment: Good answer. But why is the delay necessary? I thought JS would load normally without it and onDeviceReady was only needed if taking advantage of hardware plugins?